# Stop sentence tokenizer from splitting sentence on "no." abbreviation

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, gensim

I am trying to tokenize the following sentence type:

`"The item at issue is no. 3553."`

Every tokenizer I've tried so far returns the following (including a Punkt tokenizer trained on my corpus):

`[["the", "item", "at", "issue", "is", "no."], ["3553."]]`

Adding a "no" abbreviation to the tokenizer would be a problem for sentences ending in "no."

Comment: Replace `"no. "` with something unique like `#` using a regex: `no\. (?=\d)`. But it depends on your corpus; does it contain anything like "The answer is no. 3 would be a wrong answer."

Comment: @usr2564301 I am thinking regex will be good enough. For my use case it would be better to concatenate multiple sentences with the abbreviation in between than to split the abbreviation away from a sentence to which it belongs.

Comment: What's the ultimate purpose of tokenizing texts, in your project? For example, are you sure accurate sentence-breaks, as opposed to breaks that might be less ambiguous like paragraph-breaks, are essential? In a lot of cases, errors like this might not be a big deal. In cases where a small number of recurring, similar errors are the problem, you could add a pass that fixes them – perhaps a preprocessing regex, but it could be more efficient to work on the tokens. (EG: "if one sentence ends with 'no.' & next starts with digit, merge sentences" – likely much cheaper than regex scans on raw text.)

Comment: (If there are other similar cases, and if sometimes erroneously merging two sentences into one generally doesn't hurt the downstream task, then other heuristics might cover even more of the problem cases. For example: "every time a candidate-sentence doesn't start with a capital letter, merge it with the previous sentence".)

Comment: @gojomo I'm preprocessing a corpus for use in multi-word topic modeling. Failing to preserve the sentence structure would result in n-grams spanning sentences, which would have a variety of negative effects downstream.

Comment: I wouldn't be sure it would have actual negative effects, without testing & quantifying the hypothetical negatives. Simply accepting the bad, excessive sentence-splits is only going to eliminate some very tiny fraction of all possible n-grams, & those lost n-grams may have little contribution to topic-modeling.

Comment: On the other hand, if as is vary typical your topic-modeling is at some unit larger than sentences (like documents), then recombining all reported sentences into a single run-of-tokens per document may be sensible. That could indeed create "unnatural" sentence-spanning n-grams – but those won't necessarily hurt. Since they come from naturally-adjacent expressions, such ugly n-grams still might, statistically, indicate real topic-vs-topic distinctions – and thus improve performance on downstream evaluations of the topic model's usefulness.

Comment: More generally, a lot of things we'd prefer aesthetically (in matters like tokenization, sentence-splitting, phrase-combining, word-retention, etc), from our knowledge of 'real" language, don't necessarily matter, or have the directional effect on ultimate results we expect, in bulk text-analysis. It's certainly worth trying extra cleanup steps, but always check if they actually lift final end results, especially if they're complicated to add or time-consuming to apply.

Comment: @gojomo I can clearly envision the downstream negative effects in my model, which is not a typical topic model. Suffice it to say that for my use case, if I can preserve these particular n-grams while also minimizing sentence concatenation, I should.

Comment: Sure, if you know those are crucial, preserve them – but I've often been surprised when I thought certain fidelity was important, and it really wasn't. If in your domain you're sure the construct "no. ####" is very common and significant – more significant than the 2 unigrams 'no.' and '####' – then even without regard to any sentence-parsing limitations, you might want a processing step that combines them into a canonical form.

Answer (score 1):

Im afraid the only way for the system to understand the difference between `no.` the abbreviation and `no.` the end of sentence, is to understand the full context of the sentence.  And that is beyond the scope for basic tokenizers, and starts wandering into Machine Learning (ML) or Natural Language Processing (NLP).

That said, it might be possible with forward-looking patterns to see `no.` followed by digits.

Comment: Perhaps I should take a 3-pass approach: 1) Regex, 2) Tokenize, 3) Undo regex?

Comment: This is exactly  how it is done in research, so you are perfectly right with your three-step approach. By the way: your problem is the exact reason why it would be sound for a grammatical revision of punctuation to use doubled dots for sentences ending on abbreviations, e.g. "no..". Better also check your data for other abbreviations and add them to your list of elements to be replaced with the non-abbreviated form.

Answer (score -1):

You can first replace any occurrence of "no." with "no". This can be part of your text pre-processing.
The regex below will help:

```
>>> str='The item at issue is no 3553 and no 3554. This is also described in issue no.  7890 with details. No. 345 is the root cause'
>>> p=re.compile('([n|N]o)[.]\s*(\d+)')
>>> m=p.sub(r'\1 \2',str)
>>> m
'The item at issue is no 3553 and no 3554. This is also described in issue no 7890 with details. No 345 is the root cause'
```

After this you can apply your tokenizers.

Comment: No, because that would sub every occurrence of "no." at the end of a sentence.

Comment: I am checking for no. followed by a number. This seems to be the pattern of your data.

Comment: It is definitely possible that a sentence would begin with a number.

Comment: In that case, you are looking for a way to semantically analyse the sentence, so that no. is interpreted as 'number'. I would believe that there would be very few text example where a sentence ends in no and then the next begins with a number. In this case, a human reader could make mistakes. Also, semantic analyzers would find it difficult to differentiate because of lack of sufficient example. In my regex example above, you can try to specify the length of number to tokenize better.